# bool versus BOOLEAN in managed prototypes

Tags: c#, .net, interop

I'm trying to create a managed prototype in C# for the `[CreateSymbolicLink][1]` API function.  The prototype in WinBase.h is:

```
BOOLEAN APIENTRY CreateSymbolicLink (
    __in LPCWSTR lpSymlinkFileName,
    __in LPCWSTR lpTargetFileName,
    __in DWORD dwFlags
    );
```

And BOOLEAN is defined as a `BYTE` in WinNT.h.  Fine.  So my managed prototype should be:

```
[DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
static extern bool CreateSymbolicLink(string SymlinkFileName, string TargetFileName, UInt32 Flags);
```

At least, I would think so.  `bool` is just an alias for `System.Boolean`, a one-byte value.  But it doesn't seem to work.

I execute this code:

```
bool retval = CreateSymbolicLink(LinkFilename, TargetFilename, 0);
```

It returns `true`.  But the symbolic link isn't created.  The reason it's not created is that I'm not running with elevated privileges.  `GetLastError` returns 1314, which according to WinError.h means that I don't have the required permission.  As expected.  But why is my return value `true`?

Curiously, if I change the managed prototype to:

```
static extern byte CreateSymbolicLink(string SymlinkFileName, string TargetFileName, UInt32 Flags);
```

and my code to:

```
byte retval = CreateSymbolicLink(LinkFilename, TargetFilename, 0);
```

Then I get the expected result:  `retval` contains 0, meaning that the function failed.

I guess my bigger question is why doesn't `bool` work for `BOOLEAN` return values?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Mark the return value with an appropriate `MarshalAs` attribute:

```
[DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
[return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.U1)]
static extern bool CreateSymbolicLink(string SymlinkFileName, 
    string TargetFileName, UInt32 Flags);
```

The default marshalling for bool from native to managed code is 4 bytes--you probably got `true` back for your original bool because one of the wrongly-marshalled stack bytes was nonzero. (I'm guessing on that last part.)

Comment: This is not correct. The Win32 BOOL is 4 bytes (see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa383751.aspx). The UnmanagedType should be UnmanagedType.Bool.

Comment: CreateSymbolicLink returns BOOL (4 bytes). See: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa363866.aspx

Comment: BOOL is 4 bytes, but he's using BOOLEAN--which is 1. If the native method he's calling returned a 4-byte BOOL, he wouldn't need the `MarshalAs` attribute.

Comment: Uh .. the page you linked to states BOOLEAN, not BOOL, is the return value for that function.

Comment: Hmmm, that's right. Looks like there are old versions of this page (e.g., my local help) that have it as BOOL. I'm deleting my answer. Thanks.

Comment: "The default marshalling for bool ... is 4 bytes."  That's what I thought, but I couldn't find that in the docs.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

PInvoke with boolean types can produce unexpected results due to the differences between native and managed bools.  I wrote a blog article on this subject detailing the differences and correct ways to marshal the various types

- http://blogs.msdn.com/jaredpar/archive/2008/10/14/pinvoke-and-bool-or-should-i-say-bool.aspx

Ben M has the correct answer in this case.